# Authenticator app based 2 factor authentication

Tags: 20.04, authentication

a lot of software allows me to log in using code from the `Authenticator` app in my phone. Can we do something like that with Ubuntu 20.04 too ? I presume we would always need an internet connection to do so. Kindly do share if there any such 2FA methods we can use with 20.04. The machine I have is a desktop without a finger print scanner or camera or microphone.

Can we use GSConnect and achieve something like this ?

PS : I saw a few answers but were from 2017 and so on. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for [something like this?](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-multi-factor-authentication-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: I will try, thanks.